# uninstall epub3 reader from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

To read epub I installed from Microsoft Store  epub3 reader from TMA solutions.
But now there is no option in Control panel to uninstall it.
[epub3 reader not uninstalling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gigeP.png)
How can I remove this program from my Windows 10 laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Microsoft Store App.

Go to Windows 10, Start, Settings, Apps.  Now scroll down for epub Reader and then uninstall the app.  Uninstall is a option beside the App name when you scroll down.

Comment: Did you succeed in uninstalling the App?

Comment: You might try reinstalling Microsoft Store to see if that helps, otherwise something difficult has gone wrong with your system.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps/how-to-reinstall-windows-store-app-in-windows-10/5e4b125d-d851-4e65-a58b-da37630c9d09